# Error interrupt funcition with MPLAB X v5.30 XC8

Tags: interrupts, mplabx, xc8

I am programming a pic18f4550. When I try to compile the project I get two errors.

According to what the console indicates, they are caused by the following function.

```
void interrupt interupciones()
{
   //do something.
}
```

The errors are the following:

control.c: 126: 6: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
void interrupt interrupts ()

control.c: 126: 15: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
void interrupt interrupts ()

I have tried the following but the error persists.

```
void __interrupt my_interr(void)
{
  //do something.
}
```

If I remove the interrupt from the function then the project compiles correctly.

But doing the simulation doesn't work.

Comment: the error messages don't match your code; please actually post your code, at least from the names.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm guessing the OP ran the question through a translator and used the actual code, since "interupciones" means "interrupts". I think this is the actual code, just a translated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XC8, you need to define interrupts this way (the `myISR` can be changed to whatever you want):

```
void __interrupt() myISR(void)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Provided you are compiling against C99. The old `void interrupt myISR(void)` syntax is from XC8 2.00 or lower. They changed the way interrupts are defined after that. If you are not compiling against C99, you can also try `void interrupt() myISR(void) { ... }`.